# SEO: nofollow links next to normal links

Tags: optimization, hyperlink, seo, nofollow

this is a SEO related question.
I have a website, and I'm optimizing it for SEs.
I am writing an article on a very valuable site for my theme.
If I'm not wrong, then it's far enough 2 links to my website inside the article.
Some SEO guys told me that if I put more links then it will do more bad then good from SEO point of view.
But the editors of this portal, which I will publish my article on, want to put another 10 links inside of the article pointing to my website.
This would result in 12 links instead of 2. 
Now my questions are:
1. which is better? to have 2 links or 12?
2. if I set the 10 other link as nofollow, would that solve my problem, or the nofollow has a role only in the pagerank calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your question.

With links yes there can be to many if a page only contains links back to one site and only one  url on that site it will be seen as trying to game / manipulate the results.

I will try and explain this, the way to think about links is that each page is give one point to spend that point is then evenly distributed across every link on the page, Navigation / footer etc.

So if there are a total of 20 links then each of those links are given 0.05 of a point from the page.

So unfortunately it depends on the site and context, 12 links in this case where there are 40+ on the page would be fine. But if there are only 13 links on the page then it is more likely to hinder than help.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. Now one question: what if I put 13 links but 2 of them are pointing to my homepage, and the rest of them are pointing to different subpages? Is that good for me?

Answer (score 0):

Both are okay enough. In this case, you can you can link with 2 as well as with 12 links in all.
For 12 links, you have to use no `rel="nofollow"` `rel="noindex"` `rel="blank"` so that It cannot affects your website or content in SEO point of view.

For 2 links, you can directly add links to your external sites but, if these site pages are same you can use `rel="canonical"` so that search engine can treat these 2 like same pages.